# Unable to parse value from a XML text using XML Binding in Delphi

Tags: xml, delphi, delphi-xe8

I am unable to extract any value from the following xml file.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <env:Header/>
   <env:Body env:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
      <m:GetListOfAllLatestVariantsResponse xmlns:m="http://www.posti-care_suite.posti.nokia.com/POSTI_CareSuite_Interface.wsdl">
         <result soapenc:arrayType="n1:Variant5[1]" xmlns:n1="http://posti.nokia.com/server/caresuite/webservice/types">
            <variant xsi:type="n1:Variant5">
               <variantID xsi:type="xsd:long">7115932272</variantID>
               <name xsi:type="xsd:string">N8-00 RM-596 Country Variant United Kingdom GB Belle V6 Dark Gre</name>
               <productCode xsi:type="xsd:string">059C5Q8</productCode>
               <mandatoryFilesSize xsi:type="xsd:long">319898701</mandatoryFilesSize>
               <optionalFilesSize xsi:type="xsd:long">1045013246</optionalFilesSize>
               <files soapenc:arrayType="n1:File4[19]">
                  <file xsi:type="n1:File4">
                     <fileName xsi:type="xsd:string">RM596_059C5Q8_111.040.1511_007.vpl</fileName>
                     <relativePath xsi:type="xsd:string">Products/rm-596</relativePath>
                     <fileSize xsi:type="xsd:long">5316</fileSize>
                     <downloadURL xsi:type="xsd:string">http://nds2.fds-fire.nokia.com/p/d/fds_fire/1211/0218/7115932073/6425438C_RM596_059C5Q8_111.040.1511_007.vpl</downloadURL>
                     <checksum xsi:type="xsd:string">1680163724</checksum>
                     <checksumType xsi:type="xsd:int">1</checksumType>
                  </file>
                  <file xsi:type="n1:File4">
                     <fileName xsi:type="xsd:string">RM596_059C5Q8_111.040.1511_007.dcp</fileName>
                     <relativePath xsi:type="xsd:string">Products/rm-596</relativePath>
                     <fileSize xsi:type="xsd:long">31743</fileSize>
                     <downloadURL xsi:type="xsd:string">http://nds2.fds-fire.nokia.com/p/d/fds_fire/1211/0218/7115933784/18333A08_RM596_059C5Q8_111.040.1511_007.dcp</downloadURL>
                     <checksum xsi:type="xsd:string">406010376</checksum>
                     <checksumType xsi:type="xsd:int">1</checksumType>
                  </file>
                  <file xsi:type="n1:File4">
                     <fileName xsi:type="xsd:string">RM-596_111.040.1511_79u_prd.core.fpsx</fileName>
                     <relativePath xsi:type="xsd:string">Products/rm-596</relativePath>
                     <fileSize xsi:type="xsd:long">131593310</fileSize>
                     <downloadURL xsi:type="xsd:string">http://nds2.fds-fire.nokia.com/p/d/fds_fire/1207/3115/7087503025/RM-596_111.040.1511_79u_prd.core.fpsx</downloadURL>
                     <checksum xsi:type="xsd:string">1419340992</checksum>
                     <checksumType xsi:type="xsd:int">1</checksumType>
                  </file>
                  <file xsi:type="n1:File4">
                     <fileName xsi:type="xsd:string">RM-596_111.040.1511_01.01_Euro_1_79u_prd.rofs2.fpsx</fileName>
                     <relativePath xsi:type="xsd:string">Products/rm-596</relativePath>
                     <fileSize xsi:type="xsd:long">59185951</fileSize>
                     <downloadURL xsi:type="xsd:string">http://nds2.fds-fire.nokia.com/p/d/fds_fire/1207/3115/7087503335/RM-596_111.040.1511_01.01_Euro_1_79u_prd.rofs2.fpsx</downloadURL>
                     <checksum xsi:type="xsd:string">956264830</checksum>
                     <checksumType xsi:type="xsd:int">1</checksumType>
                  </file>
                  <file xsi:type="n1:File4">
                     <fileName xsi:type="xsd:string">RM-596_111.040.1511_377.01_default_79u.2012.20_prd.rofs3.fpsx</fileName>
                     <relativePath xsi:type="xsd:string">Products/rm-596</relativePath>
                     <fileSize xsi:type="xsd:long">46565</fileSize>
                     <downloadURL xsi:type="xsd:string">http://nds2.fds-fire.nokia.com/p/d/fds_fire/1211/0218/7115932076/2C5CE665_RM-596_111.040.1511_377.01_default_79u.2012.20_prd.rofs3.fpsx</downloadURL>
                     <checksum xsi:type="xsd:string">744285797</checksum>
                     <checksumType xsi:type="xsd:int">1</checksumType>
                  </file>
                  <file xsi:type="n1:File4">
                     <fileName xsi:type="xsd:string">RM-596_111.040.1511_377.01_default_79u.2012.20.uda.fpsx</fileName>
                     <relativePath xsi:type="xsd:string">Products/rm-596</relativePath>
                     <fileSize xsi:type="xsd:long">124438076</fileSize>
                     <downloadURL xsi:type="xsd:string">http://nds2.fds-fire.nokia.com/p/d/fds_fire/1211/0218/7115933788/4F8B5CF8_RM-596_111.040.1511_377.01_default_79u.2012.20.uda.fpsx</downloadURL>
                     <checksum xsi:type="xsd:string">1334533368</checksum>
                     <checksumType xsi:type="xsd:int">1</checksumType>
                  </file>
                  <file xsi:type="n1:File4">
                     <fileName xsi:type="xsd:string">RM596_APE_ONLY_ENO_11w36_v0.162.fpsx</fileName>
                     <relativePath xsi:type="xsd:string">Products/rm-596</relativePath>
                     <fileSize xsi:type="xsd:long">4593644</fileSize>
                     <downloadURL xsi:type="xsd:string">http://nds2.fds-fire.nokia.com/p/d/fds_fire/1112/1506/6514839560/RM596_APE_ONLY_ENO_11w36_v0.162.fpsx</downloadURL>
                     <checksum xsi:type="xsd:string">285947104</checksum>
                     <checksumType xsi:type="xsd:int">1</checksumType>
                  </file>
                  <file xsi:type="n1:File4">
                     <fileName xsi:type="xsd:string">RM-596_M001.56.emmc.fpsx</fileName>
                     <relativePath xsi:type="xsd:string">Products/rm-596</relativePath>
                     <fileSize xsi:type="xsd:long">1044986030</fileSize>
                     <downloadURL xsi:type="xsd:string">http://nds2.fds-fire.nokia.com/p/d/fds_fire/1208/2113/7087773772/8E08B787_RM-596_M001.56.emmc.fpsx</downloadURL>
                     <checksum xsi:type="xsd:string">2382935943</checksum>
                     <checksumType xsi:type="xsd:int">1</checksumType>
                  </file>
                  <file xsi:type="n1:File4">
                     <fileName xsi:type="xsd:string">RM-596_data_block</fileName>
                     <relativePath xsi:type="xsd:string">Products/rm-596</relativePath>
                     <fileSize xsi:type="xsd:long">4112</fileSize>
                     <downloadURL xsi:type="xsd:string">http://nds2.fds-fire.nokia.com/fdp/interface/FiRe/2010/6/--FID--A0A22XPGXOEFJ/--LID--FiRe1277360142761/RM-596_data_block</downloadURL>
                     <checksum xsi:type="xsd:string">166635140</checksum>
                     <checksumType xsi:type="xsd:int">1</checksumType>
                  </file>
                  <file xsi:type="n1:File4">
                     <fileName xsi:type="xsd:string">ive3_otp_template_production.bin</fileName>
                     <relativePath xsi:type="xsd:string">Products/rm-596</relativePath>
                     <fileSize xsi:type="xsd:long">40</fileSize>
                     <downloadURL xsi:type="xsd:string">http://nds2.fds-fire.nokia.com/fdp/interface/FiRe/2010/3/--FID--A0A22UMCDERPY/--LID--FiRe1269607336867/ive3_otp_template_production.bin</downloadURL>
                     <checksum xsi:type="xsd:string">3604450678</checksum>
                     <checksumType xsi:type="xsd:int">1</checksumType>
                  </file>
                  <file xsi:type="n1:File4">
                     <fileName xsi:type="xsd:string">093490v1.pcx</fileName>
                     <relativePath xsi:type="xsd:string">Products/rm-596</relativePath>
                     <fileSize xsi:type="xsd:long">8365</fileSize>
                     <downloadURL xsi:type="xsd:string">http://nds2.fds-fire.nokia.com/fdp/interface/FiRe/2010/8/--FID--A0A22UUKBNMGX/--LID--FiRe1281620803410/093490v1.pcx</downloadURL>
                     <checksum xsi:type="xsd:string">919543664</checksum>
                     <checksumType xsi:type="xsd:int">1</checksumType>
                  </file>
                  <file xsi:type="n1:File4">
                     <fileName xsi:type="xsd:string">040-093490_P4067_006.xml</fileName>
                     <relativePath xsi:type="xsd:string">Products/rm-596</relativePath>
                     <fileSize xsi:type="xsd:long">2610</fileSize>
                     <downloadURL xsi:type="xsd:string">http://nds2.fds-fire.nokia.com/fdp/interface/FiRe/2010/9/--FID--A0A22GGQDQJHV/--LID--FiRe1285052118474/24D0D5B4_040-093490_P4067_006.xml</downloadURL>
                     <checksum xsi:type="xsd:string">617665972</checksum>
                     <checksumType xsi:type="xsd:int">1</checksumType>
                  </file>
                  <file xsi:type="n1:File4">
                     <fileName xsi:type="xsd:string">RM596_059C5Q8_size_ccc_v2.0.bin</fileName>
                     <relativePath xsi:type="xsd:string">Products/rm-596</relativePath>
                     <fileSize xsi:type="xsd:long">472</fileSize>
                     <downloadURL xsi:type="xsd:string">http://nds2.fds-fire.nokia.com/fdp/interface/FiRe/2011/8/--FID--A0A22YXSWDMNO/--LID--FiRe1312914775006/E938259F_RM596_059C5Q8_size_ccc_v2.0.bin</downloadURL>
                     <checksum xsi:type="xsd:string">3912770975</checksum>
                     <checksumType xsi:type="xsd:int">1</checksumType>
                  </file>
                  <file xsi:type="n1:File4">
                     <fileName xsi:type="xsd:string">RM596_059C5Q8_size_hwc_v2.0.bin</fileName>
                     <relativePath xsi:type="xsd:string">Products/rm-596</relativePath>
                     <fileSize xsi:type="xsd:long">212</fileSize>
                     <downloadURL xsi:type="xsd:string">http://nds2.fds-fire.nokia.com/fdp/interface/FiRe/2011/8/--FID--A0A22GTHOJDFH/--LID--FiRe1312914776256/A65EB470_RM596_059C5Q8_size_hwc_v2.0.bin</downloadURL>
                     <checksum xsi:type="xsd:string">2791224432</checksum>
                     <checksumType xsi:type="xsd:int">1</checksumType>
                  </file>
                  <file xsi:type="n1:File4">
                     <fileName xsi:type="xsd:string">simlock_3gstandard_bb5_crcA59A.bin</fileName>
                     <relativePath xsi:type="xsd:string">Products/rm-596</relativePath>
                     <fileSize xsi:type="xsd:long">964</fileSize>
                     <downloadURL xsi:type="xsd:string">http://nds2.fds-fire.nokia.com/p/d/fds_fire/1111/2911/6514812504/simlock_3gstandard_bb5_crcA59A.bin</downloadURL>
                     <checksum xsi:type="xsd:string">1270261311</checksum>
                     <checksumType xsi:type="xsd:int">1</checksumType>
                  </file>
                  <file xsi:type="n1:File4">
                     <fileName xsi:type="xsd:string">RM-596_M001.56.emmc.cardverref.xml</fileName>
                     <relativePath xsi:type="xsd:string">Products/rm-596</relativePath>
                     <fileSize xsi:type="xsd:long">386</fileSize>
                     <downloadURL xsi:type="xsd:string">http://nds2.fds-fire.nokia.com/p/d/fds_fire/1208/2113/7087773773/CB9FED13_RM-596_M001.56.emmc.cardverref.xml</downloadURL>
                     <checksum xsi:type="xsd:string">3416255763</checksum>
                     <checksumType xsi:type="xsd:int">1</checksumType>
                  </file>
                  <file xsi:type="n1:File4">
                     <fileName xsi:type="xsd:string">MC_F_nocard.mcard.cardverref.xml</fileName>
                     <relativePath xsi:type="xsd:string">Products/rm-596</relativePath>
                     <fileSize xsi:type="xsd:long">131</fileSize>
                     <downloadURL xsi:type="xsd:string">http://nds2.fds-fire.nokia.com/fdp/interface/FiRe/2011/8/--FID--A0A22ALNMVCGG/--LID--FiRe1314695176834/39195667_MC_F_nocard.mcard.cardverref.xml</downloadURL>
                     <checksum xsi:type="xsd:string">957961831</checksum>
                     <checksumType xsi:type="xsd:int">1</checksumType>
                  </file>
                  <file xsi:type="n1:File4">
                     <fileName xsi:type="xsd:string">RM596_059C5Q8_007.spr</fileName>
                     <relativePath xsi:type="xsd:string">Products/rm-596</relativePath>
                     <fileSize xsi:type="xsd:long">9924</fileSize>
                     <downloadURL xsi:type="xsd:string">http://nds2.fds-fire.nokia.com/p/d/fds_fire/1211/0218/7115933803/A4CB1ED5_RM596_059C5Q8_007.spr</downloadURL>
                     <checksum xsi:type="xsd:string">2764775125</checksum>
                     <checksumType xsi:type="xsd:int">1</checksumType>
                  </file>
                  <file xsi:type="n1:File4">
                     <fileName xsi:type="xsd:string">RM596_059C5Q8_111.040.1511_007_signature.bin</fileName>
                     <relativePath xsi:type="xsd:string">Products/rm-596</relativePath>
                     <fileSize xsi:type="xsd:long">4096</fileSize>
                     <downloadURL xsi:type="xsd:string">http://nds2.fds-fire.nokia.com/p/d/fds_fire/1211/0218/7115932081/590998C6_RM596_059C5Q8_111.040.1511_007_signature.bin</downloadURL>
                     <checksum xsi:type="xsd:string">1493801158</checksum>
                     <checksumType xsi:type="xsd:int">1</checksumType>
                  </file>
               </files>
               <variantVersion xsi:type="n1:VariantVersion">
                  <swVersion xsi:type="xsd:string">111.040.1511</swVersion>
                  <certificateID xsi:type="xsd:long">0</certificateID>
                  <versions soapenc:arrayType="n1:Version[0]"/>
               </variantVersion>
            </variant>
         </result>
      </m:GetListOfAllLatestVariantsResponse>
   </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

I would like to extract values like variantID, productCode, name which are the child nodes for node "variant".

All I did was using XML Binding wizard to get the wrapper unit and threw a XMLDocument component in the form.

My code so far to parse the 'productCode':

```
procedure TForm1.ParseXMl(const aXMLText: string);
var
  EnvelopeType: IXMLEnvelopeType;
  ProductCode: string;
begin
  XMLDocument1.XML.Text := aXMLText;
  EnvelopeType := GetEnvelope(XMLDocument1);

  ProductCode := EnvelopeType.Body.GetListOfAllLatestVariantsResponse.Result.Variant.ProductCode.Text;
  Memo2.Text := 'Product Code: ' + ProductCode;
end;
```

The problem is, everytime I get empty string value for the required node values.

Comment: try with `.NodeValue` property instead

Comment: @whosrdaddy: Tried as your comment. But same problem. It doesn't return any value. I declared ProductCode as variant and changed Memo2.Text := VarToStr(ProductCode);

Comment: Hi, did you see my answer?

Answer (score 2):

Due to the poor implementation of XML namespaces in Delphi's `TXMLNodeList`, the code produced by the XML binding wizard can not work correctly. Because the root element carries a namespace, the code assumes that you have the same namespace on all childnodes. This has a side effect that the XML code can't find the correct node when the namespace changes as this is the case with `m:GetListOfAllLatestVariantsResponse`. I fail to understand why this has been implemented like this as you can have multiple namespaces on childnodes.

You can fix this following these steps:

**1) Copy files Xml.XmlDoc.pas and Xml.xmldom.pas from the source directory to your project directory and include them in your project**

**2) Modify your local Xml.XmlDoc.pas file**

change function `function TXMLNodeList.FindNode(NodeName: DOMString): IXMLNode;`

```
function TXMLNodeList.FindNode(NodeName: DOMString): IXMLNode;
begin
  Result := FindNode(NodeName, DefaultNamespaceURI);
  // --> add these lines below
  // node not found with default namespace, fallback to blank namespace
  if not Assigned(Result) then
   Result := FindNode(NodeName, '');
end;
```

**3) Modify your local Xml.xmldom.pas file**

change function `NodeMatches` to this:

```
function NodeMatches(const Node: IDOMNode; const TagName, NamespaceURI: DOMString): Boolean;
begin
 Result := ((NamespaceURI = '') or (SameNamespace(Node, NamespaceURI)) or (Node.namespaceURI= '')) and
           ((Node.NodeName = TagName) or (Node.LocalName = TagName));
end;
```

**4) modify the unit generated by the XML binding wizard**

We must reflect the fact that the `GetListOfAllLatestVariantsResponse` node uses another namespace:

```
procedure TXMLBodyType.AfterConstruction;
begin
  RegisterChildNode('GetListOfAllLatestVariantsResponse', TXMLGetListOfAllLatestVariantsResponseType, 'http://www.posti-care_suite.posti.nokia.com/POSTI_CareSuite_Interface.wsdl');
  inherited;
end;
```

Comment: Please note that the code is provided as is, I have not tested if the source code changes causes side effects.

Answer (score 1):

I did a quick test and the XML gets loaded but the accessors never find their way inside the owner document. I don't have an answer to that issue. Perhaps you need to get the original schema files instead.

Optionally, you can try to access the node using XPath:

```
procedure TForm1.btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  xmlDoc: IXMLDOMDocument;
  node: IXMLDomNode;
begin
  xmlDoc := CreateOleObject('Microsoft.XMLDOM') as IXMLDOMDocument;
  xmlDoc.async := False;
  xmlDoc.load('file.xml');
  if xmlDoc.parseError.errorCode <> 0 then
    raise Exception.Create('XML Load error:' + xmlDoc.parseError.reason);

  node := xmlDoc.selectSingleNode('//variant/productCode');
  if node <> nil then
    ShowMessage(node.text)
  else
    ShowMessage('Node not found');
end;
```

Comment: Thank you. Works as expected.  But I would like to know why it doesn't work using XML Binding wrapper unit.